# How to share Windows clipboard with Linux using TightVNC?

Tags: vnc, clipboard

I'm connecting to my Debian squeeze server through the Windows TightVNC viewer and tightvncserver on Linux.  I have put the following line in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
autocutsel -fork
```

However, this only seems to allow 1-way clipboard synchronization; the remote Linux content can be copied to the Windows clipboard, but not the other way around.

Is there some way I can copy Windows clipboard content and paste it in Linux through TightVNC?

Answer (score 9):

With the unlikely name of `vncconfig` on Linux, you can get bidirectional cutbuffer/clipboard interaction.

From the manual entry of `vncconfig`:

> **vncconfig** is used to configure and control a running instance of `Xvnc`, or any other X server with the `VNC` extension.  Note that it cannot be used to control `VNC` servers prior to version 4.
>
> When run with no options, it runs as a kind of "helper" application for `Xvnc`.  Its main purpose when run in  this  mode  is  to support  clipboard transfer to and from the `VNC viewer(s)`.  Note that without a running instance of `vncconfig` *there  will  be  no clipboard  support*.   The `vncconfig` command puts  up a window with some checkboxes which can be used to disable clipboard transfers if required.  The `-nowin` flag can be used if you always want  clipboard support but don't wish to clutter the desktop with this window 
>   Alternatively the `-iconic` option can be used to make  it  iconified by default.
>
> **Note:** The  `DISPLAY`  environment  variable  or  the  `-display` option will be used to identify the display/window in which to be active.

Using `TightVNC`on Windows, make sure that the  option  `Disable clipboard transfer` is not checked.  This option is accessible when you launch TightVNC.

You will see the Startup Window.

[image: TightVNC Startup Window]

(click on Options) then make sure that `Disable clipboard transfer` is not checked.

[image: Disable clipboard transfer]

Comment: The Debian 10 tightvncserver package (rev 1.3.9-9_deb10u1) doesn't include any "vncconfig" command.  Do you know if there is a way to configure it to support clipboard sharing?

Comment: The `vncconfig` command works perfectly with a different VNC server (I set up `tigervnc` for this test)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the TightVNC server package doesn't have this support.  At least the version I have (`tightvncserver` version 1.3.9-9+deb10u1, from Debian 10) doesn't.

It's also worth noting that the official TightVNC web site says that this version (1.3) is outdated and not supported.  Unfortunately, the current version is no longer open source and requires a commercial license.  See also https://www.tightvnc.com/licensing-server-x11.php.

As an alternative, I would suggest using the TigerVNC server, which is included in my Debian installation and is probably available for many other distros as well.  Using it, I was able to get clipboard sharing working (via the previously mentioned `vncconfig` command).

If you do upgrade to TigerVNC, however, please note the following issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/1403368/tigervnc-connection-refused-when-using-ip-address-and-accepted-with-127-0-0-1

The default installation of TigerVNC (at least for me) only allows connections from `localhost`.  I assume this is for use with SSH-tunneled connections.  A one-line configuration setting in either `/etc/vnc.conf`, `~/.vnc/vnc.conf` or the command-line when starting the VNC server will disable this, allowing connections from over the network.